# sa account gets locked out frequently

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have an sql server 2008 installed.
there are about 6 databases created and running on this server
I often get message like "SA account is locked out"

is there any specific reasons for this account being locked out?

is there any other place I need to check the reasons ( I checked the eventviwer but could not get much information)

Edit:
i found this information in teh eventviewer backups. Is this the cause?

> ```
> SQL Server failed to communicate with filter daemon launch service
> ```
>
> (Windows error: The service cannot be
>   started, either because it is disabled
>   or because it has no enabled devices
>   associated with it.
>       ). Full-Text filter daemon process failed to start. Full-text search
>   functionality will not be available.

Comment: do you still need to use mixed authentication?  It's probably easily resolvable by using windows authentication only

Answer (score 2):

Make sure the Audit Failed Logins is set on the SQL Server properties. Then you can check the SQL Server Logs to see where and/or when the connection is being attempted that locks the SA account. 
I agree with Jim B though if you can switch to Windows Auth that would fix this.

Answer (score 0):

Open Sql Server Configuration Manager.
Click SQL Server Services on the left hand side.
In the list on the right you will see all the services that SQL has on your box.  What does SQL Full-text Filtering say for Status and Log on As?

It sounds like it will be stopped and also if you double click it in the properties box that pop-up under Log On select Local Service